# Cannot access my Documents

Tags: finder, mojave, permission

I updated my iMac to 10.14.5 and seem to have some problems.

**The folder “Documents” can’t be opened because you don’t have permission to see its contents.**

The permissions look OK (not sure what default should be)

```
~$ ls -lad Documents
drwx------+ 735 ian  staff  23520 22 May 09:53 Documents/
```

Finder says I have Read & Write access

EDIT1

I used Finder to give everyone Read only access, and now I can open it.

EDIT2

```
~$ ls -leO@d Documents
drwx---r-x+ 737 ian  staff  - 23584 25 May 11:39 Documents/
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

EDIT3
I used Finder to revoke everyone access, and now I can access it normally.

```
~$ ls -leO@d Documents
drwx------+ 737 ian  staff  - 23584 25 May 11:39 Documents/
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

Comment: What the output of `ls -leO@d Documents`  The default is e.g., `drwx------+ 136 $USER  staff  - 4624 May 23 08:02 Documents` and `0: group:everyone deny delete` BTW `everyone` in Finder is suppose to be No Access.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to restart my iMac (after a power failure) and found **Pictures** was similarly affected.

Finder Get Info says I have Read & Write access, but it was blocked

I used Finder to give everyone Read only access, immediately restored No Access and now I can open it.

Comment: Why is your iMac not connected to a UPS and set to do a controlled shutdown if necessary?  This is a much better alternative then letting a power failure potentially physical damage it and or corrupt the filesystem.